# Firebase Android Response code: 400

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

> Error sending crash report
>   ait: Server did not receive report: Origin Error message: Invalid crash time, too new:seconds: 1465835646 nanos: 500000000

What does this mean?

Comment: We will need more details to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fuji's answer is a good staring point, but however it took me some time to figure out how/where to set the version code.

The easiest way is to add it to the build.grade file like the following:

```
android {
     compileSdkVersion XXX
     buildToolsVersion 'XXX'
     // ...
     defaultConfig {
         // ...
         versionCode 1
     }
     // ... 
}
```

if versionCode is not set, it default to -1, which Firebase doesn't like.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error.

In my case, my project has no version code set in build.gradle, leading BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE to be -1.

This is because I have edited build.gradle by Android Studio's Project Structure editor. I guess it removes versionCode in build.gradle.